# My div doesn't appear when I click on the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to create a poll and show the results when this one is completed. But, the answers don't appear...

Here is my page1.php:

```html
<div id="poll">
<?php
 echo "<form onsubmit='getVote(option_ID); return false;' >" ;
 
 echo "<p><b> $question_content </b></p>" ; 

 $poll_option_selection = "SELECT option_ID, option_content FROM poll_options WHERE question_ID='$question_ID'" ;
 $poll_option_result = mysqli_query ($connect,$poll_option_selection) ;
 foreach ($poll_option_result as $poll_option) { 
  $option_ID = $poll_option ['option_ID'] ;
  $option_content = $poll_option ['option_content'] ;
 ?><script type="text/javascript">var option_ID = <?php echo json_encode($option_ID) ; ?> ;</script><?php
  echo "<input type='radio' id='$option_ID' value='option' required'  /> $option_content</br>" ;
  }
 echo "<p><input type='submit'></p></form>" ;
?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var user_ID = <?php echo json_encode($user_ID) ; ?> ;

function getVote(option_ID) {
   var option_ID = document.querySelector("input[value='option']:checked").id;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (option_ID.readyState==4 && option_ID.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML=option_ID.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","./core/vote.php?user_ID="+user_ID+"&option_ID="+option_ID,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

And here is page2.php with the results, called by `getVote(option_ID)`:

```html
<?php
echo "<p><b> $question_content </b></p>" ;

$option_selection = "SELECT option_content, option_score FROM poll_options WHERE question_ID='$question_ID' ORDER BY option_score DESC" ;
$option_result = mysqli_query ($connect,$option_selection) ;
foreach ($option_result as $option) { 
 $option_content = $option ['option_content'] ;
 $option_score = $option ['option_score'] ;
 echo "
 <table>
 <th><td> $option_content : </td>
 <td><b> $option_score votes </b></td></th>
 </table>
 " ;
 }

echo "<p>Vous devez attendre 6 heures afin de pouvoir revoter</p>" ;
?>
```

Could someone explain the error to me with an example please? Because I am a beginner... Thank you.

Comment: Hit F12, what console errors do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking a string, the elements ID, for it's readyState, which won't work, you'd have to check the XMLHttpRequest object instead.

Here's really what you're doing

```
function getVote(option_ID) {
   var option_ID = document.querySelector("input[value='option']:checked").id;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( option_ID.readyState == 4 && option_ID.status == 200 ) {
        //   ^ THATS A STRING ?
      }
```

What you want to do is

```
var user_ID = <?php echo json_encode($user_ID) ; ?>;

function getVote(option_ID) {
  var option_ID = document.querySelector("input[value='option']:checked").id;
  var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("poll").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  var data = "?user_ID=" + encodeURIComponent(user_ID) + 
             "&option_ID=" + encodeURIComponent(option_ID);

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "./core/vote.php" + data, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adeno ! Your are my hero today ! :)